# Pandas importing error "ImportError: cannot import name 'FrameOrSeriesUnion' from 'pandas._typing' "

Tags: python, pandas, import, compiler-errors, anaconda

When i try the import pandas as pd , its give a this error. i cant import pandas. I reinstall pandas but its same.I tried runing promt and jupyter notebook.I am using conda env with pycharm.I tried another pc but it's same. Maybe someting is missing ? What should i do ?
this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pickle

df = pd.read_csv('weatherAUS.csv')
df.head()
df.Location.unique()
df.columns
melb = df[df['Location']=='Melbourne']
melb['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(melb['Date'])
melb.head()
plt.plot(melb['Date'], melb['Temp3pm'])
plt.show()
melb['Year'] = melb['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
melb = melb[melb['Year']<=2015]
plt.plot(melb['Date'], melb['Temp3pm'])
plt.show()
data = melb[['Date', 'Temp3pm']]
data.dropna(inplace=True)
data.columns = ['ds', 'y']
data.head()
#model eğitme
m = NeuralProphet()
model = m.fit(data, freq='D', epochs=1000)
#forecast
future = m.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=900)
forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast.head()
plot1 = m.plot(forecast)
plt2 = m.plot_components(forecast)
#save model
with open('saved_model.pkl', "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(m, f)
del m
with open('saved_model.pkl', "rb") as f:
    m = pickle.load(f)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=900)
forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast.head()
plot1 = m.plot(forecast)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas.core.algorithms import factorize, unique, value_counts
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas._typing import AnyArrayLike, ArrayLike, DtypeObj, FrameOrSeriesUnion
ImportError: cannot import name 'FrameOrSeriesUnion' from 'pandas._typing' (C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas\_typing.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this error.Pandas required NumPy, python-dateutil and pytz.I didn't have dateutil and pytz installed. So i installed dateutil and pytz.